# function for summation is works properly without return

Tags: c

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int summation(int sum)
{
    if (sum == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    int s=0;
    s = sum + summation(sum - 1);
}

void main()
{
    printf("%d", summation(5));
}
```

The code doesn't have a return line in `summation` function. But it still works as if we are returning s. It correctly gives `15` as output

Comment: Does it _finish with exit code 2_? Refer to: https://onlinegdb.com/3uw2fP1E7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without an explicit return, you have [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior). Doing what you expect is *one* possibility, but does not mean your program is working properly. In fact, it might be the most dangerous/misleading possibility.

Compiling with warnings on would have told you about this.

```
$ gcc test.c -Wall -Wextra
test.c: In function ‘summation’:
test.c:9:9: warning: variable ‘s’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     int s=0;
         ^
test.c: At top level:
test.c:13:6: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]
 void main()
      ^~~~
test.c: In function ‘summation’:
test.c:11:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

Compiling with `-Werror` would force you to address these issues.

In order to ensure the behavior of your program is defined, you should have an explicit return. You also have the potential for unbounded recursion if `sum` is less than `1`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int summation(unsigned int sum) {
    if (sum <= 1) {
        return sum;
    }
    else {
        return sum + summation(sum - 1);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%u", summation(5));
}
```

Comment: "Compiling with warnings" --> Yes!

Comment: May I ask why you removed the accepted checkmark from this answer, @AryanMane?